# SVG fill transition doesn't work when embeded by using <img> tag

Tags: svg, transition

I defined CSS transition rules in my svg. It's something like:

```
#mark #bg {
    transition: fill 200ms;
    fill: #245575;
    }

#mark:hover #bg {
    fill: #ff5c26;
    }
```

When I drag it into browser's blank page and test it, the transition works fine. But if I embed the svg into my website using `<img src="images/mark.svg" alt="">`, the transition doesn't work.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images either via `<img>` tags of via the CSS background-image image property cannot be interactive and have other restrictions in order to maintain user's privacy and security.

If you ask yourself "could I do this if the image was a .png or a .gif?" then you'll be on the right lines. Browsers have deliberately chosen to keep to the same mental model for SVG files so that the capability of images is easy to understand.

If you want transitions to work you'll need to use an `<object>` or `<iframe>` tag or embed the SVG inline in the html document.